# How to get everything after last slash in a URL?

Tags: python, parsing, url

How can I extract whatever follows the last slash in a URL in Python? For example, these URLs should return the following:

```
URL: http://www.test.com/TEST1
returns: TEST1

URL: http://www.test.com/page/TEST2
returns: TEST2

URL: http://www.test.com/page/page/12345
returns: 12345
```

I've tried urlparse, but that gives me the full path filename, such as `page/page/12345`.

Comment: If the URL might contain querystrings like `...?foo=bar` and  you don't want this; I'd suggest use `urlparse` in combination with naeg's `basename`-suggestion.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse

Comment: URLs can end with a slash. If you need `http://www.test.com/TEST1/` to return `TEST1` then all these answers aren't for you.

Comment: I'm a little disappointed that no one used the url of this question in their example :~(

Comment: @Boris: Not anymore - since your answer (and now also mine). ;-)

Answer (score 352, accepted):

You don't need fancy things, just see [the string methods in the standard library](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) and you can easily split your url between 'filename' part and the rest:

```
url.rsplit('/', 1)
```

So you can get the part you're interested in simply with:

```
url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
```

Comment: `url.rsplit('/', 1)` returns a list, and `url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]` is the bit after the last slash.

Comment: Another way to do would be: url.rsplit('/', 1).pop()

Comment: **WARNING:** This basic trick breaks completely on URLs such as `http://www.example.com/foo/?entry=the/bar#another/bar`. But basic parsing like `rsplit` is okay if you are absolutely certain there will never be any slashes in your query or fragment parameters. However, I shudder to think of how many codebases actually contain this `rsplit` code and its associated bug with query handling. **People who want ABSOLUTE SECURITY AND RELIABILITY should be using `urllib.parse()` instead! You can then use the `path` value that it returns and split THAT to ensure that you've split ONLY the path.**

Comment: **CODE: An example of how to implement the better method:** `from urllib.parse import urlparse; p = urlparse("http://www.example.com/foo.htm?entry=the/bar#another/bar"); print(p.path.rsplit("/", 1)[-1])` Result: `foo.htm`

Comment: @MitchMcMabers please turn this into an answer (which should then be the accepted one)

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz I count two non-accepted answers here that suggest exactly this for years now :)

Answer (score 95):

One more (idio(ma)tic) way:

```
URL.split("/")[-1]
```

Comment: Yes this is more straightforward than using `rsplit`.

Comment: plus 1 for the funny comment haha

Answer (score 17):

[`rsplit`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) should be up to the task:

```
In [1]: 'http://www.test.com/page/TEST2'.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
Out[1]: 'TEST2'
```

Answer (score 14):

urlparse is fine to use if you want to (say, to get rid of any query string parameters).

```
import urllib.parse

urls = [
    'http://www.test.com/TEST1',
    'http://www.test.com/page/TEST2',
    'http://www.test.com/page/page/12345',
    'http://www.test.com/page/page/12345?abc=123'
]

for i in urls:
    url_parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(i)
    path_parts = url_parts[2].rpartition('/')
    print('URL: {}\nreturns: {}\n'.format(i, path_parts[2]))
```

Output:

```
URL: http://www.test.com/TEST1
returns: TEST1

URL: http://www.test.com/page/TEST2
returns: TEST2

URL: http://www.test.com/page/page/12345
returns: 12345

URL: http://www.test.com/page/page/12345?abc=123
returns: 12345
```

Comment: Using `urlparse` is the right answer, but this will return `""` if your url ends with a `/`.

Comment: using `i.rstrip('/')` would solve the empty path when ending in /

Answer (score 13):

You can do like this:

```
head, tail = os.path.split(url)
```

Where tail will be your file name.

Comment: This won't work on systems where the path separator is not "/". One of the notes in the os.path [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) mentions a posixpath, but I couldn't import it on my system: "you can also import and use the individual modules if you want to manipulate a path that is always in one of the different formats. They all have the same interface: posixpath for UNIX-style paths"

Answer (score 10):

```
os.path.basename(os.path.normpath('/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/'))
```

```
>>> folderD
```

Comment: this also works:
```from pathlib import Path
print(f"Path(redirected_response.url).stem: {Path(redirected_response.url).stem!r}")```

Comment: [URLs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3) aren't file paths, they can contain a `?query=string` or a `#fragment` after the path.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a more general, regex way of doing this:

```
    re.sub(r'^.+/([^/]+)$', r'\1', url)
```

Comment: can you explain it a bit?

Comment: @sandoronodi. Thanks for your solution. If the url is embedded in a long string, then how can I keep the information after the last `/`? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

First extract the path element from the URL:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
parsed= urlparse('https://www.dummy.example/this/is/PATH?q=/a/b&r=5#asx')
```

and then you can extract the last segment with string functions:

```
parsed.path.rpartition('/')[2]
```

(example resulting to `'PATH'`)

Comment: or we can use `parsed.path.rpartition('/')[-1]` to get the last segment

Comment: `.partition` always returns a 3-element-tuple, so `[-1]` is `[2]`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) to get just the path and then [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the path you get from it on `/` characters:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

my_url = "http://example.com/some/path/last?somequery=param"
last_path_fragment = urlparse(my_url).path.split('/')[-1]  # returns 'last'
```

**Note**: if your url ends with a `/` character, the above will return `''` (i.e. the empty string). If you want to handle that case differently, you need to [strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) the last trailing `/` character before you split the path:

```
my_url = "http://example.com/last/"
# handle URL ending in `/` by removing it.
last_path_fragment = urlparse(my_url).path.rstrip('/', 1).split('/')[-1]  # returns 'last'
```

Answer (score 3):

The following solution, which uses `pathlib` to parse the path obtained from `urllib.parse` allows to get the last part even when a terminal slash is present:

```py
import urllib.parse
from pathlib import Path

urls = [
    "http://www.test.invalid/demo",
    "http://www.test.invalid/parent/child",
    "http://www.test.invalid/terminal-slash/",
    "http://www.test.invalid/query-params?abc=123&works=yes",
    "http://www.test.invalid/fragment#70446893",
    "http://www.test.invalid/has/all/?abc=123&works=yes#70446893",
]

for url in urls:
    url_path = Path(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path)
    last_part = url_path.name  # use .stem to cut file extensions
    print(f"{last_part=}")
```

yields:

```py
last_part='demo'
last_part='child'
last_part='terminal-slash'
last_part='query-params'
last_part='fragment'
last_part='all'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extracted_url = url[url.rfind("/")+1:];
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the url and pop the last element
`url.split('/').pop()`

Answer (score 0):

Split the URL and pop the last element

```js
const plants = ['broccoli', 'cauliflower', 'cabbage', 'kale', 'tomato'];

console.log(plants.pop());
// expected output: "tomato"

console.log(plants);
// expected output: Array ["broccoli", "cauliflower", "cabbage", "kale"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`yarl`(A URL parsing library)](https://yarl.aio-libs.org/en/latest/).

First, create a `URL` instance from a `str` object, and then [use the `name` attribute to get the last part](https://yarl.aio-libs.org/en/latest/api/#yarl.URL.name).

```
>>> from yarl import URL
>>> 
>>> URL("http://www.test.com/TEST1").name
'TEST1'
>>> URL("http://www.test.com/page/TEST2").name
'TEST2'
>>> URL("http://www.test.com/page/page/12345").name
'12345'
```

The existing solution(`url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]`) won't [work in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253803/how-to-get-everything-after-last-slash-in-a-url#comment109854998_7253830) like `http://www.example.com/foo/?entry=the/bar#another/bar`, Whereas `yarl` can provide the expected result.

```
>>> "http://www.example.com/foo/?entry=the/bar#another/bar".rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
'bar'
>>> from yarl import URL
>>> URL("http://www.example.com/foo/?entry=the/bar#another/bar").name
''
```

Answer (score -5):

```
url ='http://www.test.com/page/TEST2'.split('/')[4]
print url
```

Output: `TEST2`.

Comment: You really should pass `-1` as the index, otherwise this only works on strings with exactly that many `/`