# how to get the last part of strings with different lengths ended by ".nc"

Tags: r, string, subset, gsub

I have several download links (i.e., strings), and each string **has different length**.

For example let's say these fake links are my strings:

```
My_Link1 <- "http://esgf-data2.diasjp.net/pr/gn/v20190711/pr_day_MRI-AGCM3-2-H_highresSST_gn_20100101-20141231.nc"

My_Link2 <- "http://esgf-data2.diasjp.net/gn/v20190711/pr_-present_r1i1p1f1_gn_19500101-19591231.nc"
```

**My goals:**

**A)** I want to have only the last part of each string ended by .nc , and get these results:

```
pr_day_MRI-AGCM3-2-H_highresSST_gn_20100101-20141231.nc

pr_-present_r1i1p1f1_gn_19500101-19591231.nc
```

**B)** I want to have only the last part of each string before .nc , and get these results:

```
pr_day_MRI-AGCM3-2-H_highresSST_gn_20100101-20141231

pr_-present_r1i1p1f1_gn_19500101-19591231
```

I tried to find a way on the net, but I failed. It seems this can be done in Python as documented here:

[How to get everything after last slash in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253803/how-to-get-everything-after-last-slash-in-a-url)

**Does anyone know the same method in R**?

Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: `gsub(".*/(.*)\\.nc", "\\1", My_Link2)`

Comment: Perfectly works for the second goal. Based on your comment, I found the answer for the first goal, too. It would be like this: `gsub(".*/(.*\\.nc)", "\\1", My_Link2)` .It was a great help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shortcut to get last part of the string would be to use `basename`

```
basename(My_Link1)
#[1] "pr_day_MRI-AGCM3-2-H_highresSST_gn_20100101-20141231.nc"
```

and for the second question if you want to remove the last `".nc"` we could use `sub` like

```
sub("\\.nc", "", basename(My_Link1))
#[1] "pr_day_MRI-AGCM3-2-H_highresSST_gn_20100101-20141231"
```

---

With some regex here is another way to get first part :

```
sub(".*/", "", My_Link1)
```