# Finding location of picture for folder

Tags: python, windows, image, directory

I am organizing some books I have on my computer and at the moment they are organized like this:

how the folders with the book packages look:
[image: how the folders with the book packages look]

how the folders with the books and any supplement material look:
[image: how the folders with the books and any supplement material look]

I used this method to set the picture for the folders https://winaero.com/blog/change-folder-picture-windows-10/.

I want using python, given a folder directory to find the location of the picture I put as the folder image.

I tried to find the solution online. but could not find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

If your photos are in the name of your directory then reference this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253803/how-to-get-everything-after-last-slash-in-a-url) and use the `rsplit` string method to get everything after the last slash in your directory name.

```
directory = '/Users/max/Desktop/books/machinelearningcookbook.png'
image_name = directory.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
```

Comment: This might be useful for the question in the post but not the question in the title, as it only gives the photo name and not its location.

Comment: Yes, sorry I was unclear. I want to find the location of the picture, that is in some random folder somewhere on the computer. Thank you either way!

Comment: No problem, I'm still new too :) maybe these links will help [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python) and [Python pathlib Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)