# Read a value from the URL in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i'm trying to read the value of a url and add it to the models in django.

Basically if i have the following link

> my_site.com/special_event/123

How would i be able to catch the last part of the link the (123) and save it as an entry for my models. For context i am trying to do a raffle on my website, and when someone scans a QR code it will send them to my site and the end of the link will be a random number that i will use to raffle. So in this case a person's raffle ticket would be 123.

So far i have this code:
the model:

```
class RaffleEntry(models.Model):
entry_number = models.IntegerField(blank=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.entry_number
```

And the view i tried doing it this way:

```
def add_entry(request, entry_number):
    entry_number = RaffleEntry.objects.create()
    return render(request, 'front/entry_success')
```

I also tried to add an INT parameter to the URL like this:

```
    path('special_events/add_entry/<int:entry_number>', views.add_entry, name='special_events/add_entry>'),
```

Any help or even just point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, this is a duplicate; See the answers in this post: [how to get everything after last slash in a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253803/how-to-get-everything-after-last-slash-in-a-url)

Comment: i believe so, i think i was looking at the issue the wrong way maybe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get everything after last slash in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253803/how-to-get-everything-after-last-slash-in-a-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to do what i wanted i just had to change my Views.py, here's the code:

```
def add_entry(request, entry_number):
RaffleEntry.instance = RaffleEntry.objects.create(entry_number=entry_number)
return render(request, 'front/entry_success.html', {'entry_number': entry_number})
```

This solved it.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint
generated=[]

def generate_random_number(seed):
    random_number=(randint(0,seed))
    return str(random_number)


for i in range(0,10):
        random_number=generate_random_number(9999)
        if not random_number in generated:
        url="my_site.com/special_event/"+random_number
        url1=url
        url=(url.split("/"))
        print(url[len(url)-1], url1)
        generated.append(random_number)

print(generated)
```

> 4887 my_site.com/special_event/4887

> 682 my_site.com/special_event/682

> 3755 my_site.com/special_event/3755

> 7953 my_site.com/special_event/7953

> 8867 my_site.com/special_event/8867

> 5238 my_site.com/special_event/5238

> 9309 my_site.com/special_event/9309

> 2424 my_site.com/special_event/2424

> 3930 my_site.com/special_event/3930

> 8064 my_site.com/special_event/8064

['4887', '682', '3755', '7953', '8867', '5238', '9309', '2424', '3930', '8064']

Comment: No everyone will have the same link, that is the issue. Each QR code has it's own variation of the link

Comment: Not sure how everyone will have the same link if the last digits are generated randomly

Comment: i meant not* everyone will have the same link, i generated a whole sheet of qr codes to distribute amongst guests, each qr code will link you to my_site.com/special_event/8064 or whatever number it was randombly generated. i need to get the last numbers and save them on the database so i can use those as a raffle ticket.