# Cutting a string after the last occurrence of certain sign

Tags: python, pandas, string

Can you please help me how to disentangle the following issue. I have a column in pandas df called "names" that contains links to webpages. I need to create a variable called "total categories" that will contain the parts of the link that appears after the last appearance of "/" sign. Example:

```
names
https://www1.abc.com/aaa/72566-finance
https://www1.abc.com/aaa1/725-z2
https://www1.abc.com/aaa2/75-z3

total categories
72566-finance
725-z2
75-z3
```

I tried this code:

```
def find_index(x):
    return x.rindex('/')

data_pd['total categories'] = data_pd['names'].apply(find_index)
```

I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'rindex'
```

Comment: OK, so what have you tried so far? Does `split("/")[-1]` not work for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get everything after last slash in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253803/how-to-get-everything-after-last-slash-in-a-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with the `r'/([^/]+)$'` regex:

```
df['total categories'] = df['names'].str.extract(r'/([^/]+)$')
```

output:

```
                                    names total categories
0  https://www1.abc.com/aaa/72566-finance    72566-finance
1        https://www1.abc.com/aaa1/725-z2           725-z2
2         https://www1.abc.com/aaa2/75-z3            75-z3
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zjrlnh/1) and description:

```
/       # match a literal /
(       # start capturing
[^/]+   # one or more non-/ characters
)       # end capturing
$       # end of string
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! And is there a way to get what is coming after "integer-"?

Comment: yes sure, use `r'\d-([^-]+)$'`

Answer (score 1):

If you have these set up as columns in a pandas DataFrame, you can do the following:

```py
df['total categories'] = df['names'].str.split('/').str[-1]
```

This will split the string based on the passed delimiter, `'/'`, and then take the last element of the resulting splits.